# Were Illithids inspired by Cthulhu?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, history-of-gaming, lovecraftian

Mind Flayers seem to look a whole lot like Cthulhu. Is there any relationship/inspiration between the two?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'll suggest reading [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10039/52137) regarding this question type and that close reason.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Indirectly, yes. Gary Gygax [tells us](http://enworld.org/forum/1991676-post126.html) that "the mind flayer I made up out of whole cloth using my imagination, but inspired by the cover of Brian Lumley's novel in paperback edition, *The Burrowers Beneath*." Said novel was firmly rooted in the Cthulhu mythos; in fact, Lovecraft's character [Robert Harrison Blake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Harrison_Blake) wrote a short story titled "The Burrower Beneath." We may suspect that title was an influence on Brian Lumley's choice of titles.

The cover in question, for reference:

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, Lovecraft actually got the title from Robert Bloch, the writer of *Psycho*, who sent H.P.L. a draft of a story called "The Blasphemy Beneath". Lovecraft in turn used "The Burrower Beneath" as a title for one of Robert Blake's stories because the fictional Blake was a sort of tribute to the actual Bloch.  Bloch returned the favor by making a nameless, Lovecraft-inspired character the protagonist of his own story "The Shambler from the Stars" (itself a title derived from one of Blake's fictional books).

Comment: This is interesting. As a minor point: that creature will actually be a Chthonian, who is part of the Mythos, but is significantly different from Cthulhu. So the full answer would seem to be: Mind Flayers are inspired by the Cthulhu Mythos, but not by Cthulhu himself.

Comment: @Graham Although chthonians are pretty much big worms with tentacles at one end, so mind flayers look a lot more like Cthulhu than like chthonians.

Answer (score 3):

As Graham points out the illithids share more physical similarity to [Chthonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chthonian_(Cthulhu_Mythos)).

> Chthonians (/ˈθoʊniənz/ from Greek: chthon, "earth") are fictional
>   creatures in the Cthulhu Mythos. Chthonians as name of the species is
>   the creation of English horror-fiction writer Brian Lumley and was
>   first featured in his short story "Cement Surroundings" (1969)—though
>   the creature never made a direct appearance. The chthonians had a more
>   prominent role in Lumley's novel The Burrowers Beneath (1974), whose
>   title was taken from one of the stories said to have been written by
>   Robert Blake in Lovecraft's "The Haunter of the Dark."

The brain sucking probably refers to ["The Space-Eaters" by Frank Belknap Long](http://fantasticworlds-jordan179.blogspot.com/2013/09/the-space-eaters-1928-by-frank-belknap.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think they were definitely inspired by Cthulhu, and there's no secret that the original D&D designers and fans were very familiar with the works of HP Lovecraft. It's probably not just illithids, either. We could look closely and see a lot Mythos-inspired monsters in the earliest monster manuals as well as the newest ones.

The Cthulhu Mythos was featured in the original print-runs of [Deities and Demigod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deities_&_Demigods)s.

Comment: The Far Realms have Cthulhu written allll over them.

Comment: @Bryant No surprise there. Cthulu's big on tagging.